# Find a pattern matching a string and send the whole pattern to output

Tags: linux

I have a file with multiple patterns with below structure:

```
<DataRecord>
<TimeStamp>20170620110609-0700</Timestamp>
<User>aaaaa</User>
<Event>bbbbb</Event>
</DataRecord>
```

Same record or pattern will be repeated many times with different timestamp,user and events.

I'm trying to scan the file and find the patterns with the Event matching the value of ggggg and send it to output , considering that the i need the whole  pattern in the output (like below)

```
<DataRecord>
<TimeStamp>20170620110718-0700</Timestamp>
<User>hhhhh</User>
<Event>gggggg</Event>
</DataRecord>
```

I'm using sed -n '/ggggg/,/DataRecord/p' >> output.txt but it provides the output beginning from `<Event>gggggg</Event>` not from `<DataRecord>` till end of the record.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how much line you have to print from the matched string,then you can use the grep command

```
   grep -A1 -B3 "ggggg" filename >> output.txt
```

In the above command, A1 means one line after the matched pattern and B3 means 3 lines before the matched pattern.

Comment: Hi Manoj  , actually the lines before A is fixed and clear but after B it can vary , so its not always always a fix number of lines.